# C++ program not giving expected output

Tags: c++

Following is my code in which i am trying to find maximum pairwise product in a single array pass:

```
// A O(n) C++ program to find maximum product pair in an array


#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<conio.h>

using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

// Function to find maximum product pair in arr[0..n-1]

int MaxPairwiseProduct(const vector<long>& arr, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (n == 2)
    {
        return arr[0] * arr[1];
    }


    long posa = 0, posb = 0;


    long nega = 0, negb = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        if (arr[i] > posa)
        {
            posb = posa;
            posa = arr[i];
        }
        else if (arr[i] > posb)
            posb = arr[i];


        if (arr[i] < 0 && abs(arr[i]) > abs(nega))
        {
            negb = nega;
            nega = arr[i];
        }
        else if (arr[i] < 0 && abs(arr[i]) > abs(negb))
            negb = arr[i];
    }

    if (nega*negb > posa*posb)
        return nega*negb;
    else
        return posa*posb;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<long> numbers(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    int result = MaxPairwiseProduct(numbers, n);
    cout << result << "\n";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

It woks perfectly fine for small numbers,but when Input the following:

Input:

```
2
100000 90000
```

Output is:

```
410065408
```

instead of

```
9000000000
```

I am not able to figure out how this output is coming,I even used long instead of int to deal with large numbers.Please help me.

Comment: *sigh*.. minimal example?

Comment: You may need to use **labs()** instead of **abs()** . These must be macros, if they were functions C++ would automatically pick the right one  .[ called ' function overloading ' , done via argument signature ]

Comment: @ArifBurhan done that...still not working.

Comment: add some trace messages, and remove code that's never been executed. then update your question.

Comment: I got it....the function's type was int when it was returning a long long integer.Hence the wrong output.But,thanks,anyways!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overflow will happen if `long`or `int` (because the return value and `result` to store the result is `int`) in this environment is 32-bit long or less.

Replace type of numbers that are used to calculation to `int64_t` if you can use C++11 or later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint> // add this to use int64_t
using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

// Function to find maximum product pair in arr[0..n-1]

int64_t MaxPairwiseProduct(const vector<int64_t>& arr, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (n == 2)
    {
        return arr[0] * arr[1];
    }


    int64_t posa = 0, posb = 0;


    int64_t nega = 0, negb = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        if (arr[i] > posa)
        {
            posb = posa;
            posa = arr[i];
        }
        else if (arr[i] > posb)
            posb = arr[i];


        if (arr[i] < 0 && abs(arr[i]) > abs(nega))
        {
            negb = nega;
            nega = arr[i];
        }
        else if (arr[i] < 0 && abs(arr[i]) > abs(negb))
            negb = arr[i];
    }

    if (nega*negb > posa*posb)
        return nega*negb;
    else
        return posa*posb;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int64_t> numbers(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    int64_t result = MaxPairwiseProduct(numbers, n);
    cout << result << "\n";
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```